# Objective-C dentro do Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift-3

Existe alguma forma de colocar classes Objective-C dentro de projetos Swift?

Comment: isso se refere a criar uma classe Obj-C e usar ela no projeto ou colocar linhas de código Obj-C dentro do mesmo arquivo Swift?

Comment: Se refere a usar linhas de códigos dentro do Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie uma nova "Cocoa Touch Class" em File > New > File

Coloque Objective-C como linguagem:
[image: Criação da classe]

Após clicar para prosseguir o XCode irá perguntar se voce quer criar um Bridging Header(é a classe que ira fazer uma "ponte" entre as duas linguagens importando o código Objective-C para dentro do Swift).

Clique para criar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nesta classe importe o .h da classe que deseja usar no projeto swift, neste caso importei a classe "Import"

```
  #import "Import.h"
```

na classe Import foi criado somente um metodo para printar uma string

```
//Código do Import.h


#import 

@interface Import : NSObject

-(void) printName:(NSString*)name;

@end
```

```
//Código do Import.m

#import "Import.h"

@implementation Import
-(void) printName:(NSString*)name{
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}
@end
```

e agora é só instanciar a classe de qualquer parte do código swift e chamar seu método, como por exemplo no viewDidLoad da ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var i = Import()
   i.printName("Maria")
}
```